# Masters application with bad 1st year transcript

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

When I started the course I had a very negative attitude and did not participate or even bother trying to pass. I am not proud to say that I failed multiple subjects in my first year of degree.

In my second year I came to realize that this is the opportunity I have been given and actually started working really hard on pushing my CGPA up. I have successful done so bringing it up to 3.25 out of 4.0 from a low of 1.9. Once I started actually trying I found that I do have a passion and would love to pursue a master.

I am worried that I stand no chance because of that first year record. My question is do I stand a chance to get in a masters program and what do you think would help strengthen my application.

Answer (score 2):

Schools do like to see that students have improved overtime so you do have that going for you. I would say the answer to your question depends on the type of program you want to get into. I can only speak from research university experience but I have seen people with not great GPAs (around 3.3) get into even PHD programs if they have enough research experience (i.e. posters, papers, lab manager experience, etc.)

Comment: Yes, there is a certain amount of "forgiveness" for first year grades, because a lot of students have trouble making the transition to college.